# php explode not working as expected with string as a delimiter

Tags: php, explode

Here's what I want to do:

- get the body part of an html page and strip html tags from it
- use explode to return the text following a given string

  ```
  $html = file_get_contents($url);
  $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
  $dom = new DOMDocument;
  $dom->loadHTML($html);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  $query = $xpath->query("/html/body");
  $body = $dom->saveXML($query->item(0));
  $body = strip_tags($body);
  echo end(explode('Item description', $body));
  ```

The last line doesn't work as I expect. If I use a string with a space as a delimiter, it doesn't work (just returns everything). When I use a single word with no spaces e.g. "description", it works. What do I need to do to make it work with a phrase? I had the same problem with strpos - if $needle had a space, it would not give the right result.

UPDATE:

The source html had a `&nbsp;` between the 2 words I was using as a delimiter in `explode` i.e. `Item&nbsp;description`

I tried doing `str_replace("&nbsp;", ' ', $body);` but that didn't do anything.
However, when I did `str_replace("&nbsp;", ' ', $html);` to the html BEFORE it was processed by `$dom->saveXML` that fixed the problem.

This 
[blog post](http://daveyshafik.com/archives/705-extdom-and-libxml2-charset-and-entities-behaviors.html) made me think that `$dom->saveXML` was likely altering the html;

Comment: Have you tried using preg_split() ?

Comment: Maybe the space really isn't a space, try preg_split() with `'#Item\s+description#'` as the pattern.

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes : echo end(explode("Item description", $body));

Comment: Works fine, please provide more details: http://3v4l.org/1TiH3#v430

Comment: print our the contents of `$body` right before the explode, and double-check (view source) that it actually contains `"Item description"` as you expect. (ie. no newlines, only one space, etc)

Comment: Tried preg_split('#Item\s+description#', $body) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When your code `echo end(explode('Item description', $body));` return everything or all `$body` as string that mean `'Item description'` not found .
And When return empty string that mean the last element of return array is empty string